# Typescript with Vue js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

Hi I have a question didn't find answer/solution till now...
I am looking to include typescript in a Vue project but not directly into component level.
What I plan to do is, create some .ts files and compile them to .js files so then I can reference/import these .js files extracted from .ts and make use of them inside components... 
for example...

```
<template>
...
</template>    
<script>
  import file from './file.js';
...
</script>
<style>
...
</style>
```

then use the code from file.js inside the methods defined inside script tags in the component.
What I wanted to know... is this possible (if yes how?) and is this a good approach? I plan to use this approach for most of my components so they have a separated imported script.

Comment: As Harshal said, you'll probably end up writing everything in TypeScript. To get started I definitely recommend using Vue GUI (cli v3) to bootstrap things. It's quite a hassle to implement TypeScript manually.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible. If you are planning to write some components in TypeScript directly, your `.vue` file would look like:

```
<template>
     <!-- Some HTML -->
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import file from './file.js';
</script>
```

It is perfectly fine to have some part of your code in TypeScript and some part in JavaScript. If you are using Webpack or other, ensure that `ts-loader` and `babel-loader` are properly configured.

For TypeScript, you will want to set flags like `allowJs`, `implicit any`, disable `strict` mode to reduce friction when importing JS files into TypeScript and vice-a-versa.

As far as being the good approach, I advice to not do the workflow you are suggesting. Your mixed TypeScript and JS workflow would be:

- Use module bundler like Webpack (Rollup has problems with Vue + TypeScript)
- Compile all at once, i.e. don't wait for TypeScript compilation and then use compiled code in `.vue` files.
- Three loaders are must: `ts-loader`, `babel-loader`, `vue-loader`. Without that it is not possible.
- When using TypeScript, you won't have to specify filename extensions like `.js` or `.ts` inside import statements.
- Also, write your entry file i.e. `main.ts` or `index.ts` in TypeScript. It will save you a lot of pain.

Once you start writing and see the power of TypeScript, you will eventually start writing everything in TypeScript.